R packages broken by source library installs?
It looks like I must have installed some libraries from source a few months ago (think gdal and friends). I now have a list of apt packages which are being 'kept back'
 r-cran-jpeg r-cran-lwgeom r-cran-rgdal r-cran-rmysql r-cran-sf r-cran-stringi r-cran-terra
And having now set things up using https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/ - I strongly suspect that I have broken my system with these hand-installed libraries built from source.
Any suggestions as to how I identify the source built/installed libraries on this Debian based system?

I believe your assumption regarding gdal is correct, at least for sf, terra, and lwgeom. I encountered similar issues a while back and uninstalling all traces of GDAL, PROJ, and GEOS then reinstalling the packages that bind to them fixed it. In some cases, it appears that GDAL, PROJ, and GEOS don't get updated and new packages bind to the existing versions, or try and fail to. Check my answer here and the comments in particular, for further context. Although that link relates to MAC OS, my issue was on a PC.

From memory, I also uninstalled rgdal as well.

In the end I couldn't find any libraries 'manually installed'... so I just started removing packages... and managed to break almost everything... :(
I eventually found that I had things setup for bookworm and jammy and bullseye... so getting rid of bullseye helped :-) and eventually after a couple of hours of hair pulling I got things working again!

apparently it's a bad idea to mix ubuntu and debian package repos on the same machine... so i've removed the references to ubuntu repos... and all is well...
